# I just installed Azure CLI. When I run "az" I get the following error. Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://

Tags: azure

Azure CLI having issues with proxy settings. I have all the basic Proxies exported. This is the first app I am having trouble with Proxy settings. The error I get is:

```
C:\Users\rnalla>az login --identity --verbose --debug
Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

Comment: What exactly does "I have all the basic Proxies exported." Do you mean you have some environment variables set? Which ones? With what values?

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined the proxy settings wrong and missing prefix `http://`  i.e. `http://proxy.intra` instead  `proxy.intra`